# Is asking if some software is too buggy or safe to use considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I wouldn't be asking for recommendations, but whether a code library is considered usable in the field or whether it's too buggy and if so, why. The safety of software is based on facts considering the weight of the bugs. Would that be too opinionated?

Comment: Opinionated or not, it is still off-topic.  SO is for programming problems.  Now, for some buggy library, it may be possible to isolate a bug, post the code, and ask for the fix.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg SO is for software *and the tools commonly used for its development*, so I disagree that it's off topic - but I do agree that it's too opinionated.

Comment: As @MatthewLundberg has pointed out, if you can show how you have implemented it and what your concerns are then I don't think it's a problem. Now, depending on the tag and how frequent users of said tag feel, that may be up for debate. Just give as much detail as you can concerning how you've implemented it

Comment: @slugster it depends. If you say, "Is this software ok to use or is it too 'buggy'?", then that is off-topic. But if you say, "I've implemented this and these are my concerns.", then they may be ok.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about giving the context, what I'd use it for and how I intend to use it.

Comment: @codeMagic the seriousness of bugs are based on facts, not opinions though?

Comment: I'm not talking about "seriousness of bugs" but if someone might think it is "buggy" which is definitely up for debate. If you say,"I want to use this SW, is it buggy", that is opinion-based. If you say, "I'm using this development SW and I am seeing these bugs, is there a reasonable solution to avoid them?" (or something similar), then those are completely different questions.

Comment: @user3791372 If you believe the "seriousness of bugs" is based on facts then please quantify "seriousness" for us. Note also that questions such as "I am seeing these specific bugs, is there a workaround?", on-topic or not, are generally better answered on product-specific forums and mailing lists anyways, where the entire user base is dedicated specifically to that product. Plus, attempting to use official / dedicated support channels first is a good example of putting effort into prior research; and we *really* like that here!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's generally very difficult to make this type of question fit within the scope of SO. It will mostly have to be considered "Primarily Opinion Based". What one person considers stable software can be considered a buggy mess by another person. Partly because they might evaluate quality different, have higher stability requirements, or use it differently.

You also risk getting it closed as "Off Topic - Request to recommend...". Because you're basically asking for a recommendation on whether you should use the library, or if you should not use it.

To avoid getting your question end up in the Close queue, you'll have to find a way to turn it into a specific question that can have a technical answer which can be evaluated objectively.

Along the lines of what was already discussed in the comments above, one approach you could try would be to describe exactly how you want to use the library, and what your requirements on stability/security are. Then you could ask if people know of specific issues or caveats for your intended use of the library. Even that might end up borderline. But if you do it well, I think it might at least give you a real chance to end up with a valid question that won't get closed before you can count to 10.

Comment: +1 Also, a better source of this type of information anyways would be the internet at large (search for the library, read reviews / user comments / forum posts), as well as bug reports on the product web site (if available), discussions in the product mailing list (if available), an IRC channel dedicated to the product (if available), a forum dedicated to the product (if available), or even just general chat here or in the tavern.